# Laravel, how to modify/edit excel base on this code?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a working code in controller as shown below, problem is that when I wanted to edit its content, it doesn't save.

**Controller**

```
$rows = Excel::load($file_path, function($reader) use ($column_number)
{
    $reader->takeColumns($column_number);
    $reader->noHeading();

})->get();

$rows = $rows->toArray();
```

**View Content**

```
dump($rows[0][0]); // this will display A1 cell and it is working fine
```

But when I try to do like this

```
$rows[0][0] = "Test"; // this will not write the cell A1
dump($rows); // but it will display as shown in picture below
```

[image]

Comment: So, are you want to load file and edit it's content and save in excel again?

Comment: yes, would like to overwrite it

Comment: add your file overwrite code and error too if you getting any error

Comment: there is no error whatsoever...its just that i dont know how to achieve my goal regarding this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your file by sheet index and append your values

```
$download_file_name = 'DataFile';
 Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(1)->load($file_path, function($reader) use () {
    $reader->sheet('Sheet1', function($sheet) use () {
        //if you want to add value append single value
        $sheet->SetCellValue("A7", "Exporter");
        //if want to append row
        $sheet->appendRow($dispColArray);                  
                     });
}, 'UTF-8')->setFilename($download_file_name)->download('xls');
```

You can also use for the following function for sheet style

1. For sheet style

   ```
   $sheet->setStyle(array(
       'font' => array(
           'name' => 'Calibri',
           'size' => 9,
           'background' => '#ffffff'
       )
   ));
   ```
2. Merge cell and design

   ```
   $sheet->mergeCells('A1:D4');
   $sheet->cells('A1:D4', function($cells) {
       $cells->setBackground('#ffffff');

   });
   ```

Comment: what does `Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(1)` the `(1)` represents? and what does the variable `dispColArray` in `appendRow($dispColArray);` means?

Comment: It's your sheet number, If your file has multiple sheets then it will load 1st sheet only, For avoid exception.

Comment: Instead of putting the position `A7`, is it possible to put coordinate using `row` and `col`?

Comment: No, It's not possible. 'A'  is Column Name & '7' is Row.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the values inside the Excel Load.

```
$rows = Excel::load($file_path, function($reader)
{
    $reader->sheet('sheet1', function($sheet){
        $sheet->cells('E4', function($cell) {
            $cell->setValue('my value');
        });
    });     

})->store('xls');
```